# Xamarin.Forms show a different datatemplate for a specific item in listview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, .net-standard

I'm currently developing a dynamic app using Xamarin.Forms with .Net Standard.
I am using MVVM as code pattern. No code behind the view.

The content of the view/page is a listview bound to a list of `TemplateItem` objects. Every listview item, `TemplateItem`, should look the same (as an article). But when the property `BlockType` of the `TemplateItem` is `slideshow`, the listview must look different by using another data template.

How can I use another data template for a listview item when a property of the object is different?

Here is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             Title="Overview">

    <StackLayout >
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LstTemplateList}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate x:Name="DTArticle">
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large" />
                                    <TextCell Text="ArticleDescription"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="DTSlideShow">
                            <ViewCell>
                                <!-- another DT for a slideshow -->
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the model class:

```
public class TemplateItem
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String BlockType { get; set; }

        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String ArticleDescription { get; set; }
        public List<String> LstImagePathsForSlideshow { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a wireframe to show you what I am trying to accomplish:

[WireFrame of what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMZu1.png)

Comment: https://oren.codes/2014/12/31/datatemplateselector-for-xamarin-forms/

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using DataTemplate, try to use DataTemplateSelector. So that you can set different template for different objects.
[Reference Link :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Do what @Baduker said and I'll assure to your answer +1 =)