# Xamarin.Forms How to show a Carousel in a ViewCell

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel, .net-standard

I developing **a Xamarin.Forms** with **.NetStandard** as code sharing technique.

I have a Listview. Every item should have a template based on the property of that item. See my [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348834/xamarin-forms-show-a-different-datatemplate-for-a-specific-item-in-listview/49360008#49360008) question for more detail.

I try to show a listview item as a carousel when that item have a property with value slideshow. I already made a DataTemplateSelector that shows the right DataTemplate according the property.

I already managed to make a carousel outside the list by using "CarouselView.FormsPlugin" by "[Alex Rainman](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView)" Nuget package.

I used this package becauce the [official](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/2.3.0-pre1) Xamarin nuget package isn't supported for.Netstandard code sharing technique and it looks like it isn't updated for a while.

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:problem"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
             x:Class="problem.MainPage"
             Title="Demo Carrousel"
             x:Name="MainPage">


    <StackLayout>
        <!--// Version 1: Just on the page  WORKS-->
        <cv:CarouselViewControl  Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding CarrouselItems}" 
                                 ShowArrows="true"
                                 ShowIndicators="true"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                                 HeightRequest="250"
                               />


        <!--// Version 2: In a Viewcell of  WON'T WORK-->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LstItems}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Silver" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="Carrousel in Viewcell" />

                            <cv:CarouselViewControl  Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                 BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MainPage}"                    
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding CarrouselItems}" 
                                 ShowArrows="true"
                                 ShowIndicators="true"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                                 HeightRequest="250"
                               />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>



</ContentPage>
```

But when I try to wrap it in a `<ViewCell>` tag inside the dataTemplate for the Listview item, the app crash in **App.g.cs**:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

as shown in this image:
[image]

**How can I use a Carousel inside a ViewCell/Listview item?**

I made a demo project to illustrate my problem:
https://ufile.io/af24z

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is and with the information you provided, it's impossible to help. Please provide more code and provide an exception stacktrace.

Comment: @DennisSchröer:

I try to define my problem better.
I also prepared a demo project so you can what my problem is and better understand the problem.

I just want to make a carousel inside a ListItem via a datatemplate but as soon I wrap the carousel inside a viewcell, it wont work any more however the xaml is well defined. I think my demo application will make everything clear.

I really value your help.
Your help is much appreciated.